# Weird json nullpointer

Tags: java, android, json

I've such a weird error:
Im trying to parse json objects from a url. Which works perfect for example this is the json data:

```
{"type":"result","rid":"djoezradio",
"data":[{
"title":"Webradio",
 "song":"Test",
 "track":{
 "artist":"Test",
 "title":"Test",
 "album":"",
 "Test":422,
 "id":423,
 "playlist":{
 "id":14,"title":"reggae"
 },
 "imageurl":"http:\/\/example.com\/static\/example\/covers\/nocover.png"},
 "bitrate":"128 Kbps",
 "server":"Online","autodj":"Online","source":"Yes","offline":false","listeners":1,
 "maxlisteners":500,"reseller":0,"serverstate":true,"sourcestate":true,
 "sourceconn":true,"date":"Dec 14, 2013",
 "time":"02:13   PM","url":"http:\/\/example.com\/"}]}
```

This is my code:

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
    request.setURI(new URI("http://example.com"));
    HttpResponse response;
    try {
        response = client.execute(request);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response
                .getEntity().getContent()));
        String line = "";

        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {

            JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(line);


                String temp = jObject.getString("imageurl");
                Log.e("rid",temp);


        }
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

When i do getString("playlist") for example, it just works well, it will return id:14 etc. 
The ONLY thing which doesn't work is the object imageurl...
When i want to parse this, it just returns null, while its just there!

Any ideas?
Is there some reason? Its becouse its a .jpeg?
Pleas share, im really stuck.

Comment: Are you sure you posted the Json correctly? It has unbalanced curly braces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
request.setURI(new URI("http://example.com"));
HttpResponse response;
try {
    response = client.execute(request);
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response
            .getEntity().getContent()));

StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
String line;
while((line=in.readLine())!=null)
{

    builder.append(line);
}
String JSONdata = builder.toString();
Log.i("JsonData",JSONdata);

JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(JSONdata);


String temp = jObject.getString("imageurl");
Log.e("rid",temp);

} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (JSONException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**EDIT**

```
JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(JSONdata);

JSONArray jdata = jObject.getJSONArray("data");

JSONObject job = jdata.getJSONObject(0);
JSONObject jObjt = job.getJSONObject("track");
String temp = jObjt.getString("imageurl");
Log.e("rid",temp);
```

Comment: thnx, but still, i can parse any object, except the imageurl.... which still returns null. Log.e("JsonData", JSONdata); displays the whole json array, with the imageurl in it aswell... Still wondering why it returns null.. while it isn't.. :(

Comment: @iLuvCode what are the data you need from that json and also post that response also in log

Comment: The only data i need is imageurl. When i do for example log.e(rid, jObject.getString("playlist")) it just works, but when i want to do the same with imageurl, imageurl returns null, while the value is just there like playlist.

Comment: @iLuvCode post your full `JsonData` because need to know it's valid or not.

Comment: its valid, i posted now the whole jsondata. I checked and its valid. My problem doesn't lay there.

Comment: @iLuvCode it's invalid json here check `"offline":false"` in this you hava **"** extra